# PHP/MySQL inserting more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm having problems with inserting records in MySQL database.
It's inserting 2 or more records, instead on just one row. 
I checked the code and it's not double in the file. 
I'm using an autofill script because it's for a search bar.
When i check in the database in notice the same search query is inserted twice but from different IP Address. 
Any help would be really appreciated.

```
    //Did the member search
if(isset($_GET['searchBar'])){
    $criteria = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['searchBar']);   
    $timest = time();
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $memberid = 0;

    if(isset($_SESSION['MEMBER'])){
        $memberid = $_SESSION['MEMBER'];
    }

    function get_client_ip() {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
           $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        return $ipaddress;
    }

    $mem_ip = get_client_ip();
}
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    if (ctype_digit($_GET['page']))
    {
        $pageNum = $_GET['page'];
    }
}
else{
    if($criteria != ""){
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","USER","MYPASSWORD","DB");
    mysqli_query($con, "insert into search_queries 
    (search_query, timestamp, member_id, date, member_ip) 
    values 
    ('$criteria', '$timest', '$memberid', '$today', '$mem_ip')");
    }
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Thanks a million for this. I will make the correct changes

Comment: If you want to track down duplicates, generate a unique ID on each form and add that to your search logging table. Remember, many people habitually double click buttons for no reason whatsoever.

Comment: Ok I will try that out and let you know what i get

Comment: I'm getting 2 different ID's in the log? This means the page is reloading or something? But i can't find this reload nowhere.

Comment: If someone double clicks your script will fire twice in rapid succession. The only way to prevent this is to have the form generated with a unique identifier that's submitted and added to the database as a `UNIQUE` constraint. You can also try using JavaScript to disable the form once it's been submitted. Check your access logs carefully. Rule out possibilities.

Comment: i Get the same result when pressing enter in the form

Comment: If this code is inserting two records then it's being run twice and you need to figure out why. Stock PHP doesn't have a whole lot of debugging utilities, but I'm sure you can find some way of tracking when this code is being executed and trap the second instance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you **shouldn't use `mysql_query`**, because it's deprecated read more [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). But you can achieve what you need just by adding as many additional values as you need:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip of mysql_query. I wil make this change. But my problem is that it needs to insert only 1 instead of more.

Comment: Oh, some how i read your question wrong :D. So i think it's because script is being executed twice and the problem is not with this php segment. Can you provide more php code?

Comment: Ok, i just updated the code. Let me know if you check anything that might be causing this. Your help is really appreciated